# where to get list of countries for spinner in android

Tags: android

I would like to display a spinner in android in which the user will select a country? I know how to do the spinner but I am wondering about the the country part. Is there some sort of pre-defined list somewhere  in android (or lib) beside the fact that I have to type them manually?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve a list of countries from the android OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760341/retrieve-a-list-of-countries-from-the-android-os)

Comment: Perfect . Weird it didnt come in my search. I can accept the asnwer if posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to list all countries:

```
 Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Locale locale : locales) {
            String country = locale.getDisplayCountry();
            if (country.trim().length() > 0 && !countries.contains(country)) {
                countries.add(country);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(countries);
        for (String country : countries) {
            System.out.println(country);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);

countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     // Apply the adapter to the your spinner
            yourcountrySpinnerobj.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
```

or

Use [Geonames client libraries](http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html)

or

Use 
[geonames webservice](http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=demo)

first create your account on [Geonames](http://geonames.org) and then use that username

Answer (score 1):

Though the question asked way before and the accepted answer works well. I would like to answer the subpart of the question that asks for some library.

The [CCP library](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject) gives an easy way this task along with the flag of the country.. It allows you to make something like this really easily.
[image]

And gives powerful search feature for selection:

[image]

[1. How to use CCP for country selection?](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/wiki/Use-as-a-Country-Selector)

[2. Github Repo of CCP](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject)

Comment: Thanks thats interesting solution. Does it show cities/provinces as well of selected country?

Comment: No, it is scoped for Country Selection and Country Phone Number support.