# List of countries and ISD (calling) codes as two arrays for android spinner

Tags: android, arrays, android-spinner, country, country-codes

I need to show a list of countries in a `spinner` and when user selects a `country` i have to send its country `ISD code` to the server.

I know these are having api like [this](http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=demo) and in text way it is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes). But unfortunately I have to use it in many  places in my app. so I will be glad if i can have it in 2 arrays.(One for list of countries another one for list of codes).

list of answers [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469822/how-to-get-country-name-and-country-calling-isd-codes-in-a-spinner) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121253/where-to-get-list-of-countries-for-spinner-in-android) didn't had workout as i need list of **country names** in **array** and its **ISD codes**(not counttry codes like) in **exact order** as countries array

> **Note:** I dont need the code. I only need 2 array of values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array of countries

```
<string-array name="country_arrays">
    <item>Select Country</item>
    <item>Afghanistan</item>
    <item>Albania</item>
    <item>Algeria</item>
    <item>American Samoa</item>
    <item>Andorra</item>
    <item>Angola</item>
    <item>Anguilla</item>
    <item>Antarctica</item>
    <item>Antigua and Barbuda</item>
    <item>Argentina</item>
    <item>Armenia</item>
    <item>Aruba</item>
    <item>Australia</item>
    <item>Austria</item>
    <item>Azerbaijan</item>
    <item>Bahrain</item>
    <item>Bangladesh</item>
    <item>Barbados</item>
    <item>Belarus</item>
    <item>Belgium</item>
    <item>Belize</item>
    <item>Benin</item>
    <item>Bermuda</item>
    <item>Bhutan</item>
    <item>Bolivia</item>
    <item>Bosnia and Herzegovina</item>
    <item>Botswana</item>
    <item>Bouvet Island</item>
    <item>Brazil</item>
    <item>British Indian Ocean Territory</item>
    <item>British Virgin Islands</item>
    <item>Brunei</item>
    <item>Bulgaria</item>
    <item>Burkina Faso</item>
    <item>Burundi</item>
    <item>Cambodia</item>
    <item>Cameroon</item>
    <item>Canada</item>
    <item>Cape Verde</item>
    <item>Cayman Islands</item>
    <item>Central African Republic</item>
    <item>Chad</item>
    <item>Chile</item>
    <item>China</item>
    <item>Christmas Island</item>
    <item>Cocos (Keeling) Islands</item>
    <item>Colombia</item>
    <item>Comoros</item>
    <item>Congo</item>
    <item>Cook Islands</item>
    <item>Costa Rica</item>
    <item>Cote d\'Ivoire</item>
    <item>Croatia</item>
    <item>Cuba</item>
    <item>Cyprus</item>
    <item>Czech Republic</item>
    <item>Democratic Republic of the Congo</item>
    <item>Denmark</item>
    <item>Djibouti</item>
    <item>Dominica</item>
    <item>Dominican Republic</item>
    <item>East Timor</item>
    <item>Ecuador</item>
    <item>Egypt</item>
    <item>El Salvador</item>
    <item>Equatorial Guinea</item>
    <item>Eritrea</item>
    <item>Estonia</item>
    <item>Ethiopia</item>
    <item>Faeroe Islands</item>
    <item>Falkland Islands</item>
    <item>Fiji</item>
    <item>Finland</item>
    <item>Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>French Guiana</item>
    <item>French Polynesia</item>
    <item>French Southern Territories</item>
    <item>Gabon</item>
    <item>Georgia</item>
    <item>Germany</item>
    <item>Ghana</item>
    <item>Gibraltar</item>
    <item>Greece</item>
    <item>Greenland</item>
    <item>Grenada</item>
    <item>Guadeloupe</item>
    <item>Guam</item>
    <item>Guatemala</item>
    <item>Guinea</item>
    <item>Guinea-Bissau</item>
    <item>Guyana</item>
    <item>Haiti</item>
    <item>Heard Island and McDonald Islands</item>
    <item>Honduras</item>
    <item>Hong Kong</item>
    <item>Hungary</item>
    <item>Iceland</item>
    <item>India</item>
    <item>Indonesia</item>
    <item>Iran</item>
    <item>Iraq</item>
    <item>Ireland</item>
    <item>Israel</item>
    <item>Italy</item>
    <item>Jamaica</item>
    <item>Japan</item>
    <item>Jordan</item>
    <item>Kazakhstan</item>
    <item>Kenya</item>
    <item>Kiribati</item>
    <item>Kuwait</item>
    <item>Kyrgyzstan</item>
    <item>Laos</item>
    <item>Latvia</item>
    <item>Lebanon</item>
    <item>Lesotho</item>
    <item>Liberia</item>
    <item>Libya</item>
    <item>Liechtenstein</item>
    <item>Lithuania</item>
    <item>Luxembourg</item>
    <item>Macau</item>
    <item>Madagascar</item>
    <item>Malawi</item>
    <item>Malaysia</item>
    <item>Maldives</item>
    <item>Mali</item>
    <item>Malta</item>
    <item>Marshall Islands</item>
    <item>Martinique</item>
    <item>Mauritania</item>
    <item>Mauritius</item>
    <item>Mayotte</item>
    <item>Mexico</item>
    <item>Micronesia</item>
    <item>Moldova</item>
    <item>Monaco</item>
    <item>Mongolia</item>
    <item>Montenegro</item>
    <item>Montserrat</item>
    <item>Morocco</item>
    <item>Mozambique</item>
    <item>Myanmar</item>
    <item>Namibia</item>
    <item>Nauru</item>
    <item>Nepal</item>
    <item>Netherlands</item>
    <item>Netherlands Antilles</item>
    <item>New Caledonia</item>
    <item>New Zealand</item>
    <item>Nicaragua</item>
    <item>Niger</item>
    <item>Nigeria</item>
    <item>Niue</item>
    <item>Norfolk Island</item>
    <item>North Korea</item>
    <item>Northern Marianas</item>
    <item>Norway</item>
    <item>Oman</item>
    <item>Pakistan</item>
    <item>Palau</item>
    <item>Panama</item>
    <item>Papua New Guinea</item>
    <item>Paraguay</item>
    <item>Peru</item>
    <item>Philippines</item>
    <item>Pitcairn Islands</item>
    <item>Poland</item>
    <item>Portugal</item>
    <item>Puerto Rico</item>
    <item>Qatar</item>
    <item>Reunion</item>
    <item>Romania</item>
    <item>Russia</item>
    <item>Rwanda</item>
    <item>Sqo Tome and Principe</item>
    <item>Saint Helena</item>
    <item>Saint Kitts and Nevis</item>
    <item>Saint Lucia</item>
    <item>Saint Pierre and Miquelon</item>
    <item>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</item>
    <item>Samoa</item>
    <item>San Marino</item>
    <item>Saudi Arabia</item>
    <item>Senegal</item>
    <item>Serbia</item>
    <item>Seychelles</item>
    <item>Sierra Leone</item>
    <item>Singapore</item>
    <item>Slovakia</item>
    <item>Slovenia</item>
    <item>Solomon Islands</item>
    <item>Somalia</item>
    <item>South Africa</item>
    <item>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</item>
    <item>South Korea</item>
    <item>South Sudan</item>
    <item>Spain</item>
    <item>Sri Lanka</item>
    <item>Sudan</item>
    <item>Suriname</item>
    <item>Svalbard and Jan Mayen</item>
    <item>Swaziland</item>
    <item>Sweden</item>
    <item>Switzerland</item>
    <item>Syria</item>
    <item>Taiwan</item>
    <item>Tajikistan</item>
    <item>Tanzania</item>
    <item>Thailand</item>
    <item>The Bahamas</item>
    <item>The Gambia</item>
    <item>Togo</item>
    <item>Tokelau</item>
    <item>Tonga</item>
    <item>Trinidad and Tobago</item>
    <item>Tunisia</item>
    <item>Turkey</item>
    <item>Turkmenistan</item>
    <item>Turks and Caicos Islands</item>
    <item>Tuvalu</item>
    <item>Virgin Islands</item>
    <item>Uganda</item>
    <item>Ukraine</item>
    <item>United Arab Emirates</item>
    <item>United Kingdom</item>
    <item>United States</item>
    <item>United States Minor Outlying Islands</item>
    <item>Uruguay</item>
    <item>Uzbekistan</item>
    <item>Vanuatu</item>
    <item>Vatican City</item>
    <item>Venezuela</item>
    <item>Vietnam</item>
    <item>Wallis and Futuna</item>
    <item>Western Sahara</item>
    <item>Yemen</item>
    <item>Yugoslavia</item>
    <item>Zambia</item>
    <item>Zimbabwe</item>
</string-array>
```

The array of country codes in the same order

```
<string-array name="country_code">
    <item></item>
         <item>
            +93

        </item>
        <item>
           +355
        </item>
        <item>
            +213
        </item>
        <item>
            +1684
        </item>
        <item>
            +376
        </item>
        <item>
            +244
        </item>
        <item>
            +1264
        </item>
        <item>
            +672
        </item>
        <item>
            +1268
        </item>
        <item>
            +54
        </item>
        <item>
            +374
        </item>
        <item>
          +297
        </item>
        <item>
            +61
        </item>
        <item>
            +43
        </item>
        <item>
            +994
        </item>
        <item>
            +1242
        </item>
        <item>
            +973
        </item>
        <item>
            +880
        </item>
        <item>
            +1246
        </item>
        <item>
           +375
        </item>
        <item>
            +32
        </item>
        <item>
            +501
        </item>
        <item>
            +229
        </item>
        <item>
            +1441
        </item>
        <item>
            +975
        </item>
        <item>
            +591
        </item>
        <item>
            +387
        </item>
        <item>
            +267
        </item>
        <item>
            +55
        </item>
        <item>
            +246
        </item>
        <item>
            +1284
        </item>
        <item>
            +673
        </item>
        <item>
            +359
        </item>
        <item>
            +226
        </item>
        <item>
            +257
        </item>
        <item>
            +855
        </item>
        <item>
            +237
        </item>
        <item>
            +1
        </item>
        <item>
            +238
        </item>
        <item>
            +1345
        </item>
        <item>
            +236
        </item>
        <item>
            +235
        </item>
        <item>
            +56
        </item>
        <item>
           +86
        </item>
        <item>
            +61
        </item>
        <item>
            +61
        </item>
        <item>
            +57
        </item>
        <item>
            +269
        </item>
        <item>
            +682
        </item>
        <item>
            +506
        </item>
        <item>
            +385
        </item>
        <item>
            +53
        </item>
        <item>
            +599
        </item>
        <item>
            +357
        </item>
        <item>
            +420
        </item>
        <item>
            +243
        </item>
        <item>
           +45
        </item>
        <item>
            +253
        </item>
        <item>
            +1767
        </item>
        <item>
            +1809
        </item>
        <item>
            +670
        </item>
        <item>
            +593
        </item>
        <item>
            +20
        </item>
        <item>
           +503
        </item>
        <item>
           +240
        </item>
        <item>
            +291
        </item>
        <item>
            +372
        </item>
        <item>
            +251
        </item>
        <item>
            +500
        </item>
        <item>
            +298
        </item>
        <item>
           +679
        </item>
        <item>
            +358
        </item>
        <item>
            +33
        </item>
        <item>
            +689
        </item>
        <item>
            +241
        </item>
        <item>
            +220
        </item>
        <item>
            +995
        </item>
        <item>
           +49
        </item>
        <item>
            +233
        </item>
        <item>
            +350
        </item>
        <item>
            +30
        </item>
        <item>
            +299
        </item>
        <item>
           +1473
        </item>
        <item>
            +1671
        </item>
        <item>
            +502
        </item>
        <item>
            +441481
        </item>
        <item>
           +224
        </item>
        <item>
            +245
        </item>
        <item>
            +592
        </item>
        <item>
            +509
        </item>
        <item>
            +504
        </item>
        <item>
           +852
        </item>
        <item>
            +36
        </item>
        <item>
            +354
        </item>
        <item>
           +91
        </item>
        <item>
            +62
        </item>
        <item>
            +98
        </item>
        <item>
           +964
        </item>
        <item>
            +53
        </item>
        <item>
         +441624
        </item>
        <item>
           +972
        </item>
        <item>
            +39
        </item>
        <item>
           +225
        </item>
        <item>
           +1876
        </item>
        <item>
            +81
        </item>
        <item>
            +441534
        </item>
        <item>
            +962
        </item>
        <item>
           +7
        </item>
        <item>
            +254
        </item>
        <item>
           +686
        </item>
        <item>
            +383
        </item>
        <item>
            +965
        </item>
        <item>
           +996
        </item>
        <item>
            +856
        </item>
        <item>
           +371
        </item>
        <item>
            +961
        </item>
        <item>
            +266
        </item>
        <item>
            +231
        </item>
        <item>
            +218
        </item>
        <item>
           +423
        </item>
        <item>
          +370
        </item>
        <item>
            +352
        </item>
        <item>
            +853
        </item>
        <item>
           +389
        </item>
        <item>
           +261
        </item>
        <item>
          +265
        </item>
        <item>
           +60
        </item>
        <item>
           +960
        </item>
        <item>
            +223
        </item>
        <item>
            +356
        </item>
        <item>
            +692
        </item>
        <item>
          +222
        </item>
        <item>
           +230
        </item>
        <item>
           +262
        </item>
        <item>
           +52
        </item>
        <item>
           +691
        </item>
        <item>
           +373
        </item>
        <item>
         +377
        </item>
        <item>
            +976
        </item>
        <item>
            +382
        </item>
        <item>
           +1664
        </item>
        <item>
            +212
        </item>
        <item>
            +258
        </item>
        <item>
          +95
        </item>
        <item>
           +264
        </item>
        <item>
            +674
        </item>
        <item>
           +977
        </item>
        <item>
            +31
        </item>
        <item>
            +599
        </item>
        <item>
            +687
        </item>
        <item>
          +64

        </item>
        <item>
            +505
        </item>
        <item>
            +227
        </item>
        <item>
            +234
        </item>
        <item>
            +683
        </item>
        <item>
            +850
        </item>
        <item>
            +1670
        </item>
        <item>
            +47
        </item>
        <item>
           +968
        </item>
        <item>
           +92
        </item>
        <item>
            +680
        </item>
        <item>
            +970
        </item>
        <item>
            +507
        </item>
        <item>
            +675
        </item>
        <item>
            +595
        </item>
        <item>
           +51
        </item>
        <item>
           +63
        </item>
        <item>
           +64
        </item>
        <item>
            +48
        </item>
        <item>
            +351
        </item>
        <item>
           +1787
        </item>
        <item>
            +974
        </item>
        <item>
           +242
        </item>
        <item>
            +262
        </item>
        <item>
           +40
        </item>
        <item>
          +7
        </item>
        <item>
            +250
        </item>
        <item>
            +590
        </item>
        <item>
            +290
        </item>
        <item>
            +1869
        </item>
        <item>
            +1758
        </item>
        <item>
            +590
        </item>
        <item>
            +508
        </item>
        <item>
            +1784
        </item>
        <item>
            +685
        </item>
        <item>
            +378
        </item>
        <item>
            +239
        </item>
        <item>
            +966
        </item>
        <item>
            +221
        </item>
        <item>
            +381
        </item>
        <item>
            +248
        </item>
        <item>
           +232
        </item>
        <item>
           +65
        </item>
        <item>
           +1721
        </item>
        <item>
            +421
        </item>
        <item>
            +386
        </item>
        <item>
            +677
        </item>
        <item>
            +252
        </item>
        <item>
          +27
        </item>
        <item>
           +82
        </item>
        <item>
           +211
        </item>
        <item>
           +34
        </item>
        <item>
            +94
        </item>
        <item>
          +249
        </item>
        <item>
         +597
        </item>
        <item>
           +47
        </item>
        <item>
            +268
        </item>
        <item>
           +46
        </item>
        <item>
            +41
        </item>
        <item>
           +963
        </item>
        <item>
            +886
        </item>
        <item>
            +992
        </item>
        <item>
            +255
        </item>
        <item>
           +66
        </item>
        <item>
            +228
        </item>
        <item>
           +690
        </item>
        <item>
            +676
        </item>
        <item>
           +1868
        </item>
        <item>
           +216
        </item>
        <item>
            +90
        </item>
        <item>
           +993
        </item>
        <item>
            +1649
        </item>
        <item>
            +688
        </item>
        <item>
            +1340
        </item>
        <item>
            +256
        </item>
        <item>
            +380
        </item>
        <item>
           +971
        </item>
        <item>
            +44
        </item>
        <item>
            +1
        </item>
        <item>
           +598
        </item>
        <item>
            +998
        </item>
        <item>
            +678
        </item>
        <item>
            +379
        </item>
        <item>
            +58
        </item>
        <item>
            +84
        </item>
        <item>
           +681
        </item>
        <item>
            +212
        </item>
        <item>
            967
        </item>
        <item>
            260
        </item>
        <item>
            263
        </item>
</string-array>
```

Code to get array list from xml string array

```
ArrayList<String> arrCoutry = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_arrays)));
ArrayList<String> arrCode = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_code)));
```

Code to set it to spinner using `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.search_spinner, arrCoutry);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.search_spinner_item);
Spinner signupCountry= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.signupCountry);
signupCountry.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: country codes are not is right order as for country name