# How to get a list of countries and their cities?

Tags: android, google-api

Can any one help me to get a list of countries and a list of their cities?
Is there any google Api for getting these lists?

Comment: http://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database/free

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this once:

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

for (String countryCode : locales) {

    Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

    System.out.println("Country Name = " + obj.getDisplayCountry());
    list.add(obj.getDisplayCountry());

}
```

and set the list to adapter.

I think to get cities you have to use webservices.

Refer these links:

1) [List of countries and their cities in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764339/list-of-countries-and-their-cities-in-android)

2) [Retrieve a list of countries from the android OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760341/retrieve-a-list-of-countries-from-the-android-os])